# Android: Saving a Bitmap Graph to the Image Gallery Using OnClick Listener

Tags: android, android-widget

I am a high school student looking for help saving a bitmap image creating using a modified version of the "Sensor Graph" tutorial available here: http://code.google.com/p/amarino/downloads/detail?name=SensorGraph_02.zip&can=2&q=

This creates an oscilloscope graph based on external sensor activity, and I need to save the image (currently a bitmap) as a JPEG to the Android phone Image Gallery. I would like to do so using a button.

I have enabled OnClickListener in my SensorGraph class, an extension of the Activity class; however, the actual bitmap is created in the View class.

I would appreciate if someone could provide some code to help me save the bitmap.
I can also use a general "OnClick" command in the main.xml file; however, I believe that the method specified there would just refer back to the Activity class, so I still do not know how to save a bitmap created in the View class using a method in the Activity class.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code,

```
ImageView v1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImage);
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```